# Calculate the real time of day while in a moving jet plane

Tags: vb.net, time, date-arithmetic

Using VB.Net coding I would like to calculate what the real time is while I'm traveling in a moving jet plane. I will be using this information to remind myself when the time is close to the following times: 04:00, 13:00, 17:00, 19:00 and 21:00

The flight duration is 9 hours and 50 minutes.
The flight leaves Kennedy Airport at 12:50 and arrives in Istanbul at 05:40.

If you can show me the coding required to find 19:00 and 04:00 that would be very much appreciated and I can figure out the other times based on your coding.

I was thinking that if I can figure out how much faster 1 second is than I think I can figure out when the target times will be.

Example: If 1 second on my watch = 3 seconds while on the plane I can figure out that in 10 minutes of travel, the real time has advanced 1/2 hour.

Comment: Is you system clock set to change as you move through time zones?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. No it's not.

Comment: Do you have any GPS information available to your program?

Comment: Use UTC as your anchor time. It will be correct whatever timezone you are in.

Comment: By the way - Stack Overflow is not going to "show the coding" without you showing your code first and explaining where you are stuck.

Comment: To do that, you need to know when you will be passing into each new time zone, and decide how to handle that. If you for example pass into a new time zone at 16.30, the time will jump to 17.30, so it would never be close to 17.00.

Comment: I will not have access to GPS.

Comment: Without GPS information you need to know the speed and heading of the airplane at any given moment. Then you can calculate the time at your current position. I assume you get this data directly from the airplane? If not, how do you intend to approach the problem?

Comment: Looks like I will be passing through about 6 time zones.

Comment: Sani Huttunen: I will be heading east (forward in time zones). I was hoping to write this so I won't need to constantly ask the plane crew about the time. Is there a calculation that will let me know how much faster the time is moving forward?

Comment: Time isn't moving faster when you travel by airplane. For the passengers it actually moves a bit slower, according to Einsteins theory of Relativity.

Comment: Sani: Interesting about the theory of Relativity. I was just looking for an approximate time. Thanks for your answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot get an exact time if you don't have a GPS position or the speed and heading of the airplane. What you can do is approximate.

If flight time is 10 hours and you leave at 12.00 you would arrive at 22.00 if you were in the same timezone. The actual time at the destination would be 04.00 if you would pass 6 time zones.

This would mean that 16 passing hours is only 10 hours in "real" time. So 16/10 = 1.6 hours per real hour. This means that time moves 1.6 times faster then in "reality".

Create a program that has a timer and for every second add 0.6 seconds. Start the timer at takeoff.

Or the other way around. Trigger the timer every 1/1.6 seconds and add a second to your clock. This will of course NOT be the real time at your current position but an approximation.